# Replacing a stolen French ID card remotely (no consulate nearby)

Tags: france, identification

I am in the UK and had my wallet stolen. I'm wondering whether there's anything I can do to get a new French my card remotely (by submitting documents via post or email) since the nearest consulate is quite far and I currently do not have any time to go there in person.

Comment: Have you checked whether there is an [Honorary Consul](http://www.ambafrance-uk.org/The-Honorary-Consuls,21811) at a more convenient location?

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not possible to get a new identity document (either CNI or passport) remotely. 'Votre présence est exigée lors du dépôt de la demande pour procéder à la prise d'empreintes.' https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1759. Are you a UK resident or travelling there ?

Comment: I'm also afraid that an Honrary Consul cannot deliver new identity document. 'You cannot request a passport from an Honorary Consul as the application must be made in person at the French Consulate.'

Comment: @audionuma, Would you be able to convert your comment into an answer and provide a link?

Comment: @audionuma The page I linked to makes a distinction between ID card and passport: "The honorary Consul has an administrative role. He transfers requests from French citizens such as to be registered in the French Citizens Register, requests for ID cards, transcript of registry office, etc. You cannot request a passport from an Honorary Consul as the application must be made in person at the French Consulate."

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan : you are right. It is somehow in contradiction with the link that I and Gala provided. I wonder if it is actually possible to 'request for ID cards' at an honorary Consul.

Answer (score 3):

You have to go to the consulate (or an embassy with a *section consulaire*) [in person](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1759):

> Votre présence est exigée lors du dépôt de la demande pour procéder à la prise d'empreintes.

In my experience, you actually need to go there twice, they won't send it by post either. However, many consulates organise a "tour" to make this easier: Consular officers travel to the main cities in the country once every six months or so. You might want to check if your consulate does something like that.

Note that if you have a passport, you don't really need a national ID card so you can easily wait for a convenient time (maybe until you have another reason to go to the cities where the consulate is located?)